# CanCan can? works with :all or different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I'm trying to get CanCan set up in a rails app and I'm running into some odd behavior.

My `ability.rb` file looks like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :create, User
    can :create, Template
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

`templates_controller.rb`:

```
class TemplatesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    authorize! :create, Template
  end
end
```

So far, so good. CanCan doesn't complain when I go to `/templates`. The weird behavior starts in the view. `can?` returns false when asking about `:create` and `Template` but true when asking for `:read` or `User`.

`views/templates/index.html.erb`:

```
<% if can? :create, Template %>
Doesn't show up.
<% end %>

<% if can? :read, Template %>
Does show up.
<% end %>

<% if can? :create, User %>
Does show up.
<% end %>
```

Oh, and here's my `template.rb` Model, in case that matters:

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :title, :template, :user_id
  has_many :radlibs
  belongs_to :user

  has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
end
```

This has got me really stumped, why can I only get at certain permissions in the view, when they work in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem was 'Template' is also a class in `ActionView`. So CanCan was looking at my model in the controller, but was looking at `ActionView::Template` in the view, whereas `::Template` was my model, I'm gonna think about changing that.

```
<% if can? :create, ::Template %>
Does show up.
<% end %>

<% if can? :read, Template %>
Does show up.
<% end %>

<% if can? :create, User %>
Does show up.
<% end %>
```